# Why is my JSON not working all of a sudden?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I just swapped my code from one computer to another due to the previous computer starting to act crazy. Now when I try to use my site it does not pull any information into the divs. I really am not sure what happened here, its giving me an error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2 at JSON.parse ()

which I was not getting before.

```
<script>
        //$('#agent').change(function(){
            $(document).on('change', "#agent", function(event) { 

        //jquery
         var IEX_ID=$(this).val();


        if  (IEX_ID){
            //ajax call
            $.ajax({

                type:'POST',
                url:'GetAllData.php',
                cache:false,
                data: 'Fullname='+IEX_ID,
                success: function(data){





                    var obj = JSON.parse(data);

                    console.log(obj);



                    $('#IEX_ID').html(obj.IEX_ID);
                    $('#BalancedScore').html(obj.BalancedScore);
                    $('#CustomerEx').html(obj.CEPt);
                    $('#CEM1').html(obj.CEM1);
                    $('#CEM2').html(obj.CEM2);
                    $('#CEM3').html(obj.CEM3);
                    $('#CETlabel').html(obj.CET1);
                    $('#CET2label').html(obj.CET2);
                    $('#CET3label').html(obj.CET3);

             </script>
```

Below is the php where its pulling the array from. If I do console log it gives me " Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object" Which would generally mean I have an issue with my query. I am not finding any issues? Its the same exact code that was being used on the other computer. I am just copying all files and transferring them to see if that fixes anything. I'm not sure why everything works flawlessly on one computer but on this one its giving me these errors.

```
    <?php

    $Fullname=$_POST['Fullname'];

    if(!empty($_POST['Fullname']))


  {



            $query=$conn->query("SELECT Supervisor, Fullname, IEX_ID, BalancedScore, CEPt, CEM1, CEM2, CEM3, FCRPt, FCRM1, FCRM2, AIMPt, AIMScore, AIMCnt, ProdPt, CET1, CET2, CET3, FCRT1, FCRT2, AYHT, AYHM, M_AYHT, AYHPt, Total, skill1, skill2, skill3, skill4, skill5, skill6, skill7, skill8, skill9, skill10, skill11, skill12, skill13, skill14, skill15, skill16, skill17, skill18, skill19, IncentiveMonth FROM CurrentSC WHERE IEX_ID = '".$Fullname."' order by Fullname ASC ");


            $rowCount=$query->num_rows;

            if($rowCount>0)


            {
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                            {

                                            echo json_encode;

                   $output = array ("IEX_ID" => $row['IEX_ID'], "BalancedScore" => $row['BalancedScore'], "CEPt" => $row['CEPt'], "CEM1" => $row['CEM1'] , "CEM2" => $row['CEM2'], "CEM3" => $row['CEM3'], "FCRPt" => $row['FCRPt'], "FCRM1" => $row['FCRM1'] ,"FCRM2" => $row['FCRM2'],"AIMPt" => $row['AIMPt'],"AIMScore" => $row['AIMScore'],"AIMCnt" => $row['AIMCnt'],"ProdPt" => $row['ProdPt'],"CET1" => $row['CET1'] ,"CET2" => $row['CET2'],"CET3" => $row['CET3'],"FCRT1" => $row['FCRT1'],"FCRT2" => $row['FCRT2'],"AYHT" => $row['AYHT'],"AYHPt" => $row['AYHPt'],"M_AYHT" => $row['M_AYHT'],"AYHM" => $row['AYHM'],"Total" => $row['Total'],"skill1" => $row['skill1'],"skill2" => $row['skill2'],"skill3" => $row['skill3'],"skill4" => $row['skill4'],"skill5" => $row['skill5'],"skill6" => $row['skill6'],"skill7" => $row['skill7'],"skill8" => $row['skill8'],"skill9" => $row['skill9'],"skill10" => $row['skill10'],"skill11" => $row['skill11'],"skill12" => $row['skill12'],"skill13" => $row['skill13'],"skill14" => $row['skill14'],"skill15" => $row['skill15'],"skill16" => $row['skill16'],"skill17" => $row['skill17'],"skill18" => $row['skill18'],"skill19" => $row['skill19'],"IncentiveMonth" => $row['IncentiveMonth']);  






              echo json_encode($output);



                            }

                      }
         }


        ?>
```

Comment: Your `data` must not be in proper JSON format then. Post it?

Comment: I suspect you're getting an HTML-based error message. Try `alert`ing or `console.log`ging the `data` before attempting to process it, and post the beginning bit here.

Comment: If I do console log it gives me " Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object" Which would generally mean I have an issue with my query. I am not finding any issues? Its the same exact code that was being used on the other computer. I am just copying all files and transferring them to see if that fixes anything. 

I'm not sure why everything works flawlessly on one computer but on this one its giving me these errors.

Comment: I also added the php side of things as well.

Comment: You need to check for mysqli errors before ever posting a question like this on StackOverflow.  This is the first and most basic step in code debugging.  Is the `$_POST['Fullname']` value `Sean O'Connor`?  He's a devilish man!  May I suggest that you use mysqli's prepared statements with placeholders?

Comment: And that `echo json_encode;` doesn't look good.

Comment: When you post questions on StackOverflow, remember that other people will be trying to read your code.  Please endeavor to write clean, concise, appropriately tabbed code.

Comment: thats my fault, the echo json was actually a comment I forgot to delete when I wrote this. Its gone, and so is the problem. It was an error in my php code, I did debug but for some reason didnt put two and two together because there was no way my code could be wrong right? Technically the code was right, the column in the table was wrong ;) Sometimes the simplest things can be overlooked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncaught SyntaxError says: 
Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2 at JSON.parse ()

Which means url:'GetAllData.php'
Is likely returning a PHP error. This could be the Database, PHP update, missing function, ect... I see that same error when my PHP feeds are malformed.

QED: check the results of website.com/GetAllData.php and see if they are proper JSON.

Comment: I went back to the other computer and everything is working fine there. I am just transferring all my files from that computer to this one and starting fresh. Hopefully that works. I mean if it works over there then it is definitely correct JSON, for some reason its not working on this computer. The database did update, but that shouldn't have much of an effect. Only the dates changed.

Comment: You are right. There was something wrong with my query. I still have no idea what specifically so I deleted it all and I am re writing it. Its currently loading correctly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Malsum since this answer did not solve your question, you have inappropriately awarded the big green tick.  You are able to remove it at any time.  This answer offers clues about how to investigate, but it is not an answer -- it should be a comment.  If you remove the green tick, then this post can be dealt with appropriately in the moderation queue.

Comment: The answer did resolve my question though. Even though it should be a comment, he answered what I wanted to know. "Why am I getting this error" pretty much. He said its most likely returning a PHP error which it was. In the end since I switched computers, there was a column named Total# and json was catching the # and going crazy. I renamed the column and it fixed it. He led me in the right direction to solve my issue. Its fixed now.